# filter array method javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

could you please tell me why my script is broken?
It is an exercise in a Udemy lesson.
You need only returning users who have admin level access

```
var users = [
 { id: 1, admin: true },  
 { id: 2, admin: false },
 { id: 3, admin: false },
 { id: 4, admin: false },
 { id: 5, admin: true },
];

var filteredUsers;

function isAdmin(array, property){
     return array.filter(function(key){
        return key[property] === 'true';
})
}

filteredUsers = isAdmin(users, 'admin');
```

Thank you

Comment: `true !== 'true'`

Comment: I think `isAdmin` is a "predicate," and should be used as the function inside .filter().  Also, calling it "isAdmin" *and* giving it the property name is redundant.  Shouldn't isAdmin always know it should check the admin property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test against a boolean value, because your data has `true` or `false` values.

```
return key[property] === true;
//                       ^^^^
```

```js
function isAdmin(array, property) {
    return array.filter(function (key) {
        return key[property] === true;
        //                       ^^^^
    });
}

var users = [{ id: 1, admin: true }, { id: 2, admin: false }, { id: 3, admin: false }, { id: 4, admin: false }, { id: 5, admin: true }],
    filteredUsers = isAdmin(users, 'admin');

console.log(filteredUsers);
```

Comment: Thank you As you have pointed to the boolen value it made me understand it. I just did not realized it.

Answer (score 0):

)Your problem is that your are using the 3 equal sing ("===") to test the proprety. Here's a link with more details that explains the difference between :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/523650/5235299

Comment: Depends on your perspective.  The way I see it, using the three equal signs is the correct thing to do, but you need to compare to `true`, not to `"true"`.  But this may be a religious issue to some people (like myself ;D).

Comment: The problem was that I didn't realise the boolean values as property but strings. As Nina pointed it out I understood straight and realised my mistake.